# Compute Cech cohomology with two open sets

Tags: derived-categories, sheaf-cohomology, cech-cohomology

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a topological ringed space and $(U,V)$ be an open covering of $X$ (i.e. $U$ and $V$ are two open subsets of $X$ such that $U\cup V=X$). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. The following statement seems very natural to me although I never found it written:

> There is a quasi-isomorphism, natural in $\mathcal{F}$, $R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\stackrel{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{cone}[-1](R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F})\stackrel{(1,-1)}{\longrightarrow}R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}))$ in the derived category of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$-modules.

Does anyone got some hints or references?
Many thanks

Comment: This looks like a version of the Mayer-Vietoris triangle.

Comment: Many thanks @LeoAlonso, it indeed seems to be the following lemma https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CRS